# Debugging the sending of bulk emails

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, debugging, amazon-web-services

my application allows user to send many emails in one go. The thing is if the user selects many emails at once for e.g. 4000+. It shows `connection time out`. And I'm not able to debug the problem, I have tried to increase the script execution time but no luck.

I need a suggestion or a way to debug it mainly.

I'm using Amazon's SES with php framework Codeigniter.

Here's the code in controller:

```
function send_email(){



    $data = array();
    $sub = $this->input->post('subject');
    $msg = $this->input->post('message_email');
    $msg = str_replace("\r\n", '<br>',$msg);
    $msg = str_replace("\r", '<br>',$msg);
    $msg = str_replace("\n", '<br>',$msg);
        $emails = $this->input->post('email');
        $emails = explode(",",$emails);


            $message_m = $msg;

                $msg_t = '<html><body>';
                $msg_t .= $message_m;
                $msg_t .= '</body></html>';


                $this->load->library('email');

                    $config = array(
                        'protocol' => 'smtp',
                        'smtp_host' => 'email-smtp.us-west-2.amazonaws.com',
                        'smtp_user' => 'user',
                        'smtp_pass' => 'pass',
                        'smtp_port' => 25,
                        'mailtype' => 'html'
                    );
                    foreach ($emails as $em) {

                        $this->email->initialize($config);

                        $this->email->from('something@somewhere.com', 'Somename');


                        $this->email->to($em);

                        $this->email->subject($sub);
                        $this->email->message($msg_t);
                        $this->email->set_newline("\r\n");


                        $this->email->send();

                    }


            $this->index();


  }
```

Answer (score 2):

A few thoughts and solutions:

If you want to know how many emails you can safely send without it timeing out. I would debug using a log file and print a line every few emails.
So use a counter and every 100 emails or so print a line with a timer so you can see when it breaks and how long it takes to send 100 emails).

I would also make sure you know sending that many emails in one go is allowed with Amazon. Maybe you should use the sleep function every few hundred emails. If it is not allowed that may be what the script is waiting for.

Another suggestions about the codeigniter email class. You only have to initialise it once and use the $this->email->clear(true); function to reset all variables. So initialize once and use:

```
$this->email->clear(TRUE); // you can omit the TRUE if you don't have attachements
```

That should save some loading time.

It looks like you are sending the same message to diffenent users so maybe bcc is an option (so you can make fewer calls to amazon). I don't know if this is possible with Amazon though, it could be considered spam that way.